# Procfile not declared Django Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, procfile

My `Procfile` not getting declared.

Not Declared:

[image]

File Location:

[image]

Comment: Is your `Procfile` encoded as UTF-8? It's hard to tell from your screenshot; is that file in the root directory of your project? Is it committed? Are you pushing the correct branch?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.